# How to access public api in hasura

Tags: graphql, hasura

I'm running a docker container with `admin secret`. In the below image, you can see the roles under the permissions window.
[image]

For `category` table, I set `public` role for `SELECT` option and there is no restriction for that role to access any query.

[image]

But my problem is I can't access the query using `public` role, hasura engine ask `admin-secret`. see the below image.
How can I access this API without giving admin credentials?
[image]

Comment: Have you set `HASURA_GRAPHQL_UNAUTHORIZED_ROLE` to "public" or used --unauthorized-role=public flag in the startup command?

Comment: @avimoondra I didn't set that during startup

Comment: That's likely the issue! Looks like you are running in JWT mode, and have not passed "Authorization: Bearer <JWT>" header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant docs: https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/auth/authentication/unauthenticated-access.html#unauthenticated-public-access

If you are using webhook-based authentication, "for unauthenticated access, you can return a `200` status response with your defined unauthenticated role, e.g: `{ "x-hasura-role": "<anonymous-role>" }`."

If you are using jwt-based authentication, "you can use the env variable `HASURA_GRAPHQL_UNAUTHORIZED_ROLE` or `--unauthorized-role` flag to set a role for unauthenticated (non-logged in) users."

The unauthenticated role can be called anything, in your case it would be "public"

Comment: Do i have to pass HASURA_GRAPHQL_UNAUTHORIZED_ROLE this in request header with value anonymous. I have set up this role and made public api. Now, i wanted to call that api from Apollo. My Hasura instance is set up with JTW mode. But some api i wanted to access from apollo in vue app as public to which I have also set up HASURA_GRAPHQL_UNAUTHORIZED_ROLE role

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the `HASURA_GRAPHQL_UNAUTHORIZED_ROLE` to the unauthorized role name in the env variables of the cloud console [sample config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKI6T.png)

in my case, it's called `public`, then subsequent request should use the following header

`x-hasura-default-role`: `public` without any need for JWT or Admin.